# How to configure docker-compose in order to mount disk to folder , instead on local disk

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

We are using Single Node Basic Deployment on Docker that include the following services

```
kafka
schemaregistry
zookeeper
```

example:

```
# docker-compose ps
               Name                           Command            State                     Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
control-center                       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp
kafka-single-node_kafka_1            /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
kafka-single-node_schemaregistry_1   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
kafka-single-node_zookeeper_1        /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

We created the services on containers according to - https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/single-node-client.html

We create the topics on kafka machine , and we intend to inject data to the topics partitions

Topics will create on kafka docker container machine on path - `/var/lib/kafka/data`

Since `/var` on that kafka docker machine is only 100G , and we want to use size as 1T at least

Therefore we plan to add a *new disk* to the OS with 1T Byte ( 1000G )

Once we add the Huge disk , the second action is to mount the disk to `/var/lib/kafka/data` ( so data folder will be with 1T size )

But the question is - which docker configuration file/s and parameters should be set ?

We are using the `docker-compose.yml` that include the following section for kafka

```
kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Comment: Are there any volumes mounted? looks like the docker-compose does not show any volumes yet. If so the data inside the container would be lost, if the container is gone.

Comment: as I know for now no

Comment: Are the data important? Or is it okay, if you lose it.

Comment: this is kafka machine !!, data is very important

Comment: this is part of the solution - https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/cp-docker-images/docs/operations/external-volumes.html

Comment: This setup doesn't sound so safe, I have to say. Single node, no data redundancy, running the app with docker compose, no volumes yet. If anything crashes the data could get corrupt, then there's no guarantee to rescue the data. I would suggest, you setup a better environment, a cluster, volumes with enough space, and replicate the data.

Comment: did you read the article? - https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/cp-docker-images/docs/operations/external-volumes.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201917/discussion-between-jessica-and-manuel-polacek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would mount the disk to a directory in `/etc/fstab` on the linux host, then use volumes - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

```
kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    volumes: 
        - /some/path:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Comment: Dear cricket thank you so much , but one important question please , what in case kafka docker container is goes down ? , what will be in mounted folder ? as /some/path ?  ( +1 for you )

Comment: another question additional to what I asking , lets say I want to export the kafka configuration file as - server.properties outside from the kafka container , for example to /var/kafka/server.properties ( of the OS itself ) . then what is your suggestion ?

Comment: You can add multiple volumes. Having external config will be overwritten by env-vars for the Confluent containers, though. And if the container restarts on the same host, then the same volume will need to be mounted.

Comment: about the - env-vars for the Confluent containers , can you please give me example - step by step ( since I am new in docker world )

Comment: you can also answer the following thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721206/how-to-tune-edit-add-change-the-kafka-docker-container-parameters-outside-from-t