# How to tune/edit/add/change the kafka docker container parameters outside from the container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

We have kafka docker container as the following ( on Linux redhat 7.5 )

We created the kafka service on the container according to - https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/single-node-client.html

```
docker-compose ps
               Name                           Command            State                     Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kafka-single-node_kafka_1            /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
```

---

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
     0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                       kafka-single-node_schemaregistry_1
de584963bb5a        confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"   6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                       kafka-single-node_kafka_1
```

about - docker-compose.yml

```
pwd
/home/cp-docker-images/examples/kafka-single-node

more docker-compose.yml

kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

We want to control the kafka docker container configuration -  `/etc/kafka/server.properties` outside from the container , ( or from the OS itself )

Let say I want to add some parameters or to change some parameters in `server.properties` ( of the kafka container )

*so what is the best why to do the configuration outside from the kafka container*

In the following example I show how to access the `server.properties` , inside The docker kafka container

```
docker exec -it de584963bb5a    bash
```

Now we can access/read the file - `server.properties`

```
root@de584963bb5a:/# more /etc/kafka/server.properties
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
.
.
.

##################### Confluent Proactive Support ######################
# If set to true, and confluent-support-metrics package is installed
# then the feature to collect and report support metrics
# ("Metrics") is enabled.  If set to false, the feature is disabled.
#
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true


# The customer ID under which support metrics will be collected and
# reported.
#
# When the customer ID is set to "anonymous" (the default), then only a
# reduced set of metrics is being collected and reported.
#
# Confluent customers
# -------------------
# If you are a Confluent customer, then you should replace the default
# value with your actual Confluent customer ID.  Doing so will ensure
# that additional support metrics will be collected and reported.
#
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous

############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startu
p.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We want to control the kafka docker container configuration - /etc/kafka/server.properties outside from the container

I would avoid mounting a server.properties file from the host since every setting within the container can be configured by environment variables like `KAFKA_(variable)` - https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration

Rather, you can [use `env_file` for the compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) and move all your variables there

```
kafka:
   image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    env_file:
      - broker1.env
```

broker1.env

```
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
```

And you can add any broker config with this pattern -  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: this is also good explain - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-docker-env-file/

Comment: other quastion - lets say I want to set the parameter - log.segment.bytes=3746372  in server.properties , then how to set this parameter in  docker-compose.yml?

Comment: `.env` file is different than an explicit `env_file` declaration, but did you see the link I provided to Confluent docs? `KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES=3746372`

Comment: in the link - https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration , I not found the parameter - KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES

Comment: something isn't clearly , do you mean each kafka paramer have the equivalent syntax in yamel file , for example - offsets.retention.minutes is OFFSETS_RETEMTION_MINUTES ?  ( and how docker know that this parameter belongs to server.properies ?

Comment: `"uses variables prefixed with KAFKA_ with an underscore (_) separating each word"` ... That applies to **everything** at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs . Docker does not know this. Confluent wrote scripts in the container to do this

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.3.1-post/debian/server/include/etc/confluent/docker/kafka.properties.template#L12-L15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201924/discussion-between-jessica-and-cricket-007).

Comment: I will tell you what is my problem , for now I am using ambari parameters and there values , and we want to move to kafka docker , so each parameter in ambari will convert to docker , so according to what you say , I understand that all kafka parameters as shown in ambari config can converted to docker yamel file as KAFKA_ with an underscore - am I correct ?

Comment: ok , but since I used very old HDP as 2.6.4 , and old kafka version 0.1 , how to know that all my parametes are accepted by the latest docker kafka version ?

Comment: 1) Never use `:latest` tag 2) Use a versioned Kafka documentation link, for example - https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#brokerconfigs

Comment: what is the reason to not use latest kafka versions in docker ?

Comment: Because the latest image tag can change at any moment and break your container when re-pulled. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/806

Comment: still not understand if we can use all parameters  as is from ambari config from old kafka version as 0.1 ( HDP 2.6.4 ) to kafka docker as 2.X version?

Comment: Kafka does not have a 0.1 version. You can compare https://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html#brokerconfigs against https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#brokerconfigs , and I suspect there is very little change